# How to get the output data from perl subroutine passing a reference

Tags: perl, hash

How to get the data output from a perl subroutine..? Pass an hash reference to subroutine "get_data"... fill the data inside the subroutine.. and it should reflect outside.

ex:

```
my %myhash = ();
get_data(\%myhash);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;


my %myhash = ();
get_data(\%myhash); #pass hash ref
$myhash{k2} = "Hello SO"; #add one more key value
print Dumper($hash_ref); #Dump hash ref

sub get_data{
my $hash_ref = shift; #get hash ref
$hash_ref->{k1} = "adding one more key value"; #fill data
}
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'k2' => 'Hello SO',
      'k1' => 'adding one more key calue'
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the hash by reference, any changes in the hash would be visible outside the subroutine as well.

Did you face any problem with this code?

Comment: ya... the data i was inserting into hash was not reflecting outside.

Comment: @naveen: it will reflect outside the subroutine, see my answer, and still you have problem then better to show your piece of code.